# NPM run watch cant find module webpack

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a package.json which contains some packages. Once i use `npm install` it will install all the items required, but it also creates symlinks:

```
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/lodash -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lodash
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/promise -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/promise
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/underscore -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/underscore
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/less -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/axios -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/axios
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/bootstrap -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bootstrap
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/bootstrap-sass -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bootstrap-sass
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/cross-env -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cross-env
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/jquery -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jquery
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/js-cookie -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/js-cookie
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/laravel-echo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/laravel-elixir -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/laravel-elixir
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/laravel-mix -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/laravel-mix
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/less-loader -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less-loader
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/moment -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/moment
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/spinkit -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/spinkit
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/pusher-js -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pusher-js
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/sweetalert -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sweetalert
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/toastr -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/toastr
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/urijs -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/urijs
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/v-tooltip -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/v-tooltip
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/vue-codemirror -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-codemirror
/Users/donny/Sites/Homestead/node_modules/vue -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue
```

After this i try to run `npm run watch` and then i get the error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score -2):

Please check your index.html it should be

```html
<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- all code from node_modules directory is here -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script> // <-- Include this line.

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

This problems can also be easily solved by reinstalling your Ionic and Cordova.

Comment: This has nothing to do with NPM